# ¿Cifrar contraseñas o calcular un Hash para proteger los datos del usuario?

Tags: php, encriptación

Estuve leyendo sobre seguridad informática, y revisando los modos de proteger información de los usuarios.

Encontré varias guías y obtuve lo que podría ser un patrón para proteger bien un sistema:

1) Estructurar bien nuestras sentencias SQL

2) Utilizar sentencias preparadas y valores parametrizados (Mysqli statement)

3) Sanitizar nuestro documento HTML

4) Validar los campos con javascript

5) Proteger al usuario con el hasheado o la encriptación de su contraseña

Por lo que me surge la duda del paso 5, como proteger las contraseñas de los usuarios, pues estuve leyendo también sobre encriptación y hay muchos sitios web que rompen los códigos de encriptación y también leyendo sobre Hash que parece ser mas seguro, pero sale que los métodos son también inseguros.

(http://php.net/manual/es/faq.passwords.php)

En conclusión, ¿que método es mas eficiente?, ¿encriptación?, ¿hash?, ¿método nativo de php?

Por otro lado, ¿se puede crear un código de encriptación propio? algo como sha2017 por ejemplo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el contexto que implicas (AMP) para mantener un nivel de seguridad se hace generalmente lo siguiente con la criptografía:

- Usar conexión segura ([HTTPS](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol_Secure)), que ya implementa encriptación asimétrica (RSA) para negociar contraseñas simétricas para una sesión con encriptación simétrica.
- Guardar contraseñas como hash criptográfico (actualmente tipicamente [SHA-1 o SHA-256](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Hash_Algorithm), a causa del descubrimiento de vulnerabilidades se recomienda cambiar a SHA-384 o otras alternativas) para evitar descubrimiento de contraseñas en el caso que un atacante obtiene acceso a la base de datos.

El primer punto protege todos los datos transferidos entre servidor y cliente contra ataques de tipo ["man in the middle"](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ataque_de_intermediario), alguien que escucha a los paquetes intercambiados entre cliente y servidor.

Guardar y contraseñas en la base de datos como *hash* y comparar los *hash* para autorizar accesos tiene la ventaja que aun que si un atacante obtiene acceso a la base de datos directo o por copias de seguridad **solamente** el *hash*. Como es prácticamente imposible de reconstruir una contraseña desde un *hash* criptográfico, y en el acceso se envía la contraseña, no el hash, eso evita que:

- el atacante con el *hash* puede acceder el sistema con lo que obtuvo,

y que

- el atacante no obtiene una contraseña de un usuario que podría probar en otros sistemas o deducir patrones como el usuario elige sus contraseñas.

Por la segunda razón es una cosa de cortesía de implementar buena seguridad hasta en sistemas que no tienen nada de contenido critico o muy relevante. Aun que se recomienda a todos los usuarios de no usar la misma contraseña en más que un sistema, muchos lo hacen igual por razones de comodidad y problemas de memoria.

Hacía de la pregunta si se puede inventar un propio *hash*, por supuesto que si se puede, pero requiere un **muy** bien entendimiento de matemática, criptografía y programación, y sin especializarse en estos tema probablemente es más recomendable en confiar en los algoritmos actualmente considerados los suficientes seguros.

**Importante:**

Ningun nivel de encriptación puede proteger un sistema a una contraseña mal eligida. Si alguien con un acceso privilegiado a un sistema critico usa el nombre de su esposa, que tiene publicado como pareja en su cuenta de facebook, ya puede ser una razón para ser despedido.

**¿Debería usar un *hash* costoso (lento) para mejorar mi seguridad?**

Muchos opinan eso, y se entiende por que. Un ataque fuerza bruta es mas costoso si el *hash* es más costoso para calcular. Sin embargo personalmente lo véo más como una decisión de la arquitectura. A un lado gano en seguridad, pero si hablemos de un buen algoritmo sin vulnerabilidades, buena distribución y pocas o sin colisiónes, un ataque por fuerza bruta para empezar no es factible, y al otro lado gasto más recursos por solicitud en mi sistema.

**¿Que pueda hacer para ganar un poco de seguridad extra?**

Usa un [*salt*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sal_(criptograf%C3%ADa)) o mejor aun un [HMAC](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) con las contraseñas. Guarda el *salt* o la clave del *HMAC* en una parte del sistema aparte de la base de datos donde se guardan los *hash*. Así si un atacante obtiene acceso a la base de datos, pero no al *salt*/*HMAC* toda fuerza bruta no le sirve para nada, y más encima evita que se pueden usar *hashes* pre-calculados que se pueden encontrar en listas de sitios dedicado a proveer herramientas de intruso.

Comment: la conexion https ya se esta implementando en el servidor donde ira la aplicacion, pero aun no me queda claro con que funciones o librerias utilizar

Comment: Si un usuario se conecta por `https`, no hay que hacer ningun esfuerzo extra. Hay que asegurarse que un certificado instalado en el servidor web, el resto maneja openssl junto con el servidor (Abache, Nginx, Lighttpd o lo que usas). Solamente deberías asegurarte que no ofreces una pagina con ingreso o uso de contraseña en http.

Comment: un compañero de trabajo hizo una insersion sql y se trajo los usuarios de la bd, pues todos estan en texto plano, deberia usar sha256?

Comment: Si no quieres algo completamente fuera de lo común, recomiendo usar un HMac-Sha256 por ejemplo.

Comment: otra cosita, tengo es php 5.4.3 encontre esta libreria https://github.com/Antnee/phpPasswordHashingLib Serviria?

y para eso que me dices aplico el codigo que sale en php.net de password_hash

Comment: ya lo utilice y funciona perfecto

Answer (score 2):

> En conclusion, que método es mas eficiente?, encriptacion?, hash?, método nativo de php?

Según entiendo, en criptología algo es eficiente si se lleva mucho tiempo/dinero en descifrar. No importa si este algoritmo es reversible o irreversible (este ultimo conocido como hash).

Encriptacion reversible se usa para el transporte/almacenamiento seguro de informacion, es decir que no pueda leerse el contenido original si no se tiene la clave.

Irreversible tiene otras aplicaciones como validar autenticidad y/o que un documento no fue adulterado o para almacenar contraseñas.

En cuanto a contraseñas tiene la ventaja que no dependes de una (o multiples) claves para su desifrado simplificando el mantenimiento/escalabilidad del metodo.

La clave esta en utilizar un algoritmo que requiera de mucho CPU para su calculo, de modo que un atacante que se hizo del hash del password necesite mucha fuerza de CPU para encontrar la clave (tendra que probar todas las combinaciones hasta encontrar una coincidencia).

Actualmente `scrypt` (antes bcrypt, antes MD5, antes crypt) es considerado una buena opción para cifrar contraseñas justamente porque es costoso de calcular y en consecuencia muy caro hacer un ataque masivo.

Sin embargo el algoritmo no es tan importante como la complejidad de la contraseña. Como puedes ver [aqui](https://www.grc.com/haystack.htm), una contraseña de 8 caracteres puede hallarse en 2.2 segundos (con los medios apropiados). Y una de 16 con simbolos, numeros y mayuscula, demora varias centurias.

Aclaracion: Este nivel de proteccion empieza a operar cuando tu archivo/tabla de contraseñas ya ha sido comprometida y ya está en poder de un atacante. Ademas de estos mecanismos de proteccion, es muy importante que dicho medio de almacenamiento este bien protegido (de propios y ajenos). El escenario de un ataque online lo descarto en el analisis.-

> Por otro lado, se puede crear un código de encriptacion propio? algo como sha2017 por ejemplo?

Cualquiera puede hacer un código, pero no son habilidades de programador las que necesitas sino las de un matemático. El algoritmo de cifrado/decifrado o uno de hash es una cuestión matemática. Luego se construye un programa parar ejecutarlo. Mi opinion personal es... Aceptalo, la criptografia es complicadisima y es mejor dejarselo a los matematicos.

Comment: Buena respuesta, pero no crees que la elección de un algoritmo lento es más una decisión de arquitectura? Si necesito un sistema que procesa lo más autenticaciones que posible un buen hash rápido como SHA-256 puede ser  preferible tomando en cuenta la probabilidad de armar un ataque exitoso por fuerza bruta con una clave de 256bits.

Comment: Yo no lo pensaria demasiado y usaria lo mejor que pueda ofrecerle de proteccion a mis usuarios y lo aclararia en las politicas de privacidad del sistema porque se que la gente usa las misma clave una y otra vez. Sin embargo, por eso prefiero usar OAuth2 y autenticar por google/facebook. Prefiero no tener que cargar con la responsabiliad tan sensible informacion.

Comment: Concuerdo, pero "lo mejor" esta basado en opiniones ;D. Por lo mismo mencioné en mi respuesta la opción de usar un salt, que acaba con el problema de  hashes conocidos para contraseñas como "amorcito".

Comment: @StefanNolde "lo mejor" tambien esta basado en opinones. concuerdo: el vino, la cerveza y el fernet, la pizza, el rock & roll, los bares, la noche.. XD

Comment: Yo hice algunas aclaraciones tambien sobre la complejidad de la contraseña.

Answer (score 1):

Ya que tu pregunta se basa un poco en opiniones, voy a dejar un artículo que me gustó mucho sobre el correcto uso en seguridad.

¿Todavía hay programadores web que utilizan funciones *hash criptográficas* rápidos como `MD5` y `SHA1` para almacenamiento de contraseñas en el 2015? Ha quedado claro para los expertos en seguridad que esta es una mala práctica.

La solución más fácil: Uso `libsodium`, que proporciona una `API` de hash de contraseñas seguras en la mayoría de los idiomas. Desde la `versión 1.0.9`, `libsodium` entrega `ARGON2`, la más reciente, algoritmo seleccionado cuidadosamente desde el hashing de contraseñas en la competencia. `Libsodium` ofrece fijaciones para la mayoría de los lenguajes de programación.

[Documentación Libsodium](https://download.libsodium.org/doc/)
[Librería Libsodium](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium)
[Fuente](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/02/how-safely-store-password-in-2016)

Si, por cualquier razón, no puede conciliar sus necesidades con la instalación de `libsodium`, usted tiene otras opciones.

**Sistemas de almacenamiento de contraseñas aceptables**

Según profesionales e investigadores de la seguridad existen solo 4 algoritmo de hash de confianza:

- Argon2
- bycrypt
- scrypt
- PBKDF2 *(Password-Based Key Derivation Function #2)*

Para la mayoría de los desarrolladores de `PHP` los cuales no pueden instalar paquetes `PECL` en sus entornos de producción, `scrypt` no es una opción. Si puede utilizar `scrypt`, por favor, úsenlo.

Dada la posibilidad de elegir entre `bcrypt` y `PBKDF2`, debamos elegir `bcrypt`.

Además, deben utilizar el existente `password_hash()` y  `password_verify()` en lugar de escribir su propia aplicación basada en `crypt()`.

Debemos abstenernos de generar nuestra propia *Salt*; dejar que `password_hash()` se ocupa a generar dicho *Salt*.

**Limitaciones de bcrypt**

*Hay dos advertencias en `bcrypt` que cada desarrollador debe tener en cuenta:*

Se trunca contraseñas de `72` caracteres y también en `NULL` bytes. Muchos desarrolladores tratan de resolver el problema de límite de `72` caracteres por *pre-hash* de la clave del usuario, lo que puede desencadenar la segunda.

**Un ejemplo peligroso:**

```
$almacenado = password_hash(hash('sha256', $_POST['password'], true), PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
// ...
if (password_verify(hash('sha256', $_POST['password'], true), $almacenado)) {
     // La contraseña coincide :D
} else {
    // La contraseña no coincide :(
}
```

Existe la posibilidad de no trivial que uno de los `bytes` primas en el `hash` habrá `0x00`. Cuanto antes este `byte` aparece en la cadena, el costo de encontrar una colisión se vuelve exponencialmente más barato.

Por ejemplo, tanto `1]W` y `@1$` produce una salida de hash `SHA-256` que comienza con `ab00`.

La solución, por tanto, sería pasar el hash `SHA-256` da salida a través de prima `base64_encode()` antes de pasarlos a `bcrypt`:

```
$almacenado = password_hash(
    base64_encode(
        hash('sha256', $_POST['password'], true)
    ),
    PASSWORD_DEFAULT
);
// ...
if (password_verify(
    base64_encode(
        hash('sha256', $_POST['password'], true)
    ),
    $almacenado
)) {
    // La contraseña coincide :D
} else {
    // La contraseña no coincide :(
}
```

El ejemplo anterior no se trunca a los `72` caracteres y es totalmente segura binario, por lo que los primeros `bytes` nulos no conducirá a la debilidad de la seguridad. Lo mejor de ambos mundos.

Además, es posible que desee utilizar `SHA-384` en lugar de `SHA-256`, desde `SHA-256` es vulnerable a los ataques de la longitud de extensión y `SHA-384` no lo es.

Mas información:
[Código Fuente](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/04/secure-authentication-php-with-long-term-persistence#title.2)

Comment: Encuentro PASSWORD_DEFAULT una pésima idea para el caso de uso típico, en que el _hash_ se guarda en una base de datos. Después de una actualización de php quedan todos los usuarios fuera del sistema, porque se cambió el algoritmo de hash en php? ;)

Comment: @stefanNolde según el artículo que leí, expertos en seguridad aconsejan que debemos abstenernos de generar nuestra propia Salt; dejar que password_hash() se ocupa a generar dicho Salt.  https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/04/secure-authentication-php-with-long-term-persistence#title.2

Comment: Si password_hash() implementa un salt interno que causa que un hash en tu sistema no se calcula al mismo resultado que en otro sistema, eso te da un buen nivel de seguridad extra, pero al mismo tiempo te saca control sobre tu arquitectura. Lo que el articulo básicamente dice (y es muy sabio) es que **no implementa seguridad sin saber lo que haces**. Este tema en su profundidad es demasiado amplio para comentarios.

Comment: @StefanNolde Segun tengo entendido para resolver dicho problema, dice el manual de PHP sobre PASSWORD_DEFAULT, cabe señalar que con el tiempo esta constante puede (y probablemente lo hará) cambiar. Por tanto, se debería considerar que la longitud del hash resultante puede cambiar. Así, si se emplea PASSWORD_DEFAULT se debería almacenar el hash resultante de forma que se pueda almacenar más de 60 caracteres (255 es el ancho recomendado).