# ¿Cómo proteger las contraseñas en scripts PHP?

Tags: php, contraseña, ofuscación

¿Cómo podría ocultar o proteger las contraseñas dentro de los scripts de `PHP` utilizando un método de encriptación más segura que `eval` y el uso de `base64_encode`?

He utilizado este tipo de método, pero es fácil utilizar sus *contrarios* para obtener las claves (por ejemplo con conexiones a base de datos), ¿cómo asegurarlo aún más?

El problema es que alguien más que tenga acceso al servidor pueda ver las contraseñas en texto plano, por eso este método.

```
eval(gzinflate(base64_decode('s7fjsrFXSE3OyFdQKUssykxMykm1VrC34+UCigMA')));
```

Comment: Hola @iuninefrendor en la siguiente [pregunta y variedades de respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/56302/cifrar-contrase%C3%B1as-o-calcular-un-hash-para-proteger-los-datos-del-usuario?rq=1) encontraras una gran documentación bien detallada, trata siempre de buscar preguntas similares, y si aquellas preguntas no aclaran su duda, plantear una pregunta con más base, has saber que has investigado. Saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Meter las contraseñas como variable de entorno y obtenerlas con [getenv](http://php.net/manual/es/function.getenv.php)
string getenv ( string $varname )

```
<?php
 $password = getenv('DB_PASSWORD');
?>
```

2) Añadirlas a un archivo con permisos estrictos permisos de lectura. dentro del servidor

Answer (score -2):

Podrías utilizar sha-512, md5 o algun otro cifrado para ocultarlas.

Comment: Hola @JavierArturoHernandezSosa por favor añade más detalle a su respuesta, las respuesta con poca información no son bienvenidas en SO, ***Lo que has publicado como respuesta debería ser como comentario, ya tienes la reputación necesaria para añadir comentarios*** te invito a recorrer [como dar una buena respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)  Saludos!