# ¿Cómo proteger información sensible de miradas indiscretas en PHP?

Tags: php, seguridad

Generalmente en una aplicación hay información sensible que se quiere proteger de miradas indiscretas, por ejemplo, la contraseña de acceso a la base de datos.

Yo uso este archivo, guardado en una carpeta oculta y con el acceso restringido:

```
<?php return; ?>
; credentials
host=localhost
user=myUser
pass="my/very/secure/password.../UqMsN[)VPn&gunmv3KzE?3Q&Qw/..."
dbname=myDataBase
```

La línea: `<?php return; ?>` es para que no muestre nada de lo que hay en el archivo en caso de que alguien pudiera acceder a él por URL.

Otros niveles de protección serían por ejemplo proteger contra escritura los archivos PHP que usen las credenciales.

**¿Corre mi información algún riesgo de acceso (demostrable)**?

**¿Conocen alguna otra forma de proteger la información sensible?**

> - Pregunta relacionada: [¿Cifrar contraseñas o calcular un Hash para proteger los datos del usuario?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/56302/29967)
>     Esta pregunta no trata lo que pregunto aquí, yo hablo de una
>     protección a nivel de archivos.
>
>   La duda surgió [debido a un comentario](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/209517/pdo-class-wrapper?noredirect=1#comment404954_209517) sobre mi archivo `ini` de parte de un experto en PHP. Él es el autor del sitio [`phpdelusions.net`](https://phpdelusions.net) en el cual he aprendido muchísimo.

Comment: Cuando hablas de miradas indiscretas ¿a quien te quieres referir exactamente? Alguien con acceso a los archivos, con acceso a la aplicación...

Comment: sugiero usar reglas de .htaccess... para prevenir el acceso a dicho archivo

Answer (score 4):

Una opción como lo maneja Laravel por ejemplo es dejar las credenciales de acceso en un archivo `.env` y que al momento de hacer el despliegue en el servidor quede por fuera de la carpeta de publicación; es decir:

Si la carpeta para publicar es:

`www`

Entonces el archivo debe quedar fuera de esta para que los demás usuarios no lo puedan acceder; quedando así

```
.env
www
```

Ahora por ejemplo y siguiendo las recomendaciones de la documentación de Laravel pero extrapolandolas a un desarrollo en PHP puro

Lo único que debes evitar es con git subir ese archivo a donde colocarás todo el proyecto

Para el caso de los persmisos.

Generalmente uno de los puntos que los nuevos no nos detenemos a leer es que tipo de permisos de usuarios tienen asignados nuestros archivos; a lo que voy es

Algunos usuarios tienen como práctica común hacer esto:

```
chmod -R 777
```

Sin conocer realmente que con lo anterior le estamos dando permisos totales a los usuarios sobre nuestros arcvhivos

Cuando tal vez una opción mas válida sería

```
chmod -R 700
```

Lo anterior aplicado a una carpeta que contiene los archivos que no deseamos que puedan: *leer, ejecutar o alterar demás usuarios* va a dejarnos como únicos usuarios con la posibilidad de afectar al archivo o carpeta pero no ningún otro ajeno

Comment: La 1ª técnica ya la había contemplado, el archivo está en una carpeta oculta fuera del directorio público.

Comment: la agregué aunque pareciera tema del framework Laravel, por que hace tiempo se filtro una enorme lista de webs construidas con esta herramienta; cuyo .env era visible por que estaba al mismo nivel que el resto de archivos y carpetas y se origina por un descuido/desconocimiento del tema tratado

Comment: Yo estoy en hosting compartido y el archivo se encuentra en una carpeta oculta fuera de `public_html`, (sería el equivalente a `www` de Laravel). En el hosting compartido a cada usuario le asignan una carpeta `home`, yo puedo ver la mia y no la de los otros usuarios y viceversa, supongo. Lo que tengo que ver es que nivel de permisos tengo para esa carpeta, en caso de que otro usuario se pueda colar del lado de mis carpetas o que otro usuario sufra un hackeo o algo así.

Comment: precisamente asi, aunque existirán seguro mas respuestas verificar el nivel de permisos sobre archivos y carpetas ayuda