# ¿Cómo evitar que datos de archivo .ini se muestren en ruta?

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy realizando un trabajo en php el cual contiene un folder llamado `.conf` que a su vez almacena un archivo de tipo `ini` llamado **cf.ini**.

Como servidor utilizo **usbWebServer**.

Al momento de poner la ruta de mi archivo me muestra el contenido de este.

[image: Imagen del Problema]

Lo que necesito es que no me muestre ningun dato.

Comment: Me parece raro. Yo tengo algo parecido y no se muestra nada ([ver aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/221529/29967)). De todos modos, conviene poner este tipo de archivos en carpetas no accesibles vía web (fuera del root) y además ponerlo en una carpeta `.oculta`

Comment: @A.Cedano de hecho me base en su código y en unas explicaciones que me dio hace un año, pero en esta ocasión me mostró los datos

Comment: Bueno, en mi caso el archivo tiene una extensión `php`, por ejemplo: `archivo.php.ini`no sea si será por eso.

Comment: @A.Cedano creo que era eso, me interesan sus aportaciones, de que forma pudiera preguntarle(chat o algo).

Comment: Yo respondo a las preguntas directamente aquí cuando estoy disponible. En esta comunidad hay más gente capacitada para ayudar. Si en algo necesitas una ayuda en particular me puedes mencionar en un comentario en la pregunta por ejemplo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escribir

```
<?php return; ?>
```

Evita en efecto que lo que hay más abajo se muestre en pantalla, porque lo que se indica al archivo es que retorne, que no pase de ahí.

Pero para que esto funcione tu archivo debe tener la extensión `.php`, puedes llamarle así por ejemplo: `cf.php.ini` y en ese caso debería funcionar. Al no tener extensión `.php` la línea `<?php return; ?>` no se ejecuta como código PHP sino que se interpreta como texto.

Otra cosa es que puedes simplificar tu archivo, generalmente la notación `[Seccion]` es para separar el archivo por secciones cuando se quiere organizar un archivo más complejo. No creo que aquí se justifique separar valores comunes en secciones.

Puedes ponerlo así:

```
<?php return; ?>
; credenciales
host=localhost
usuario=Usuario
clave="pass"
dbnombre=BDEjemplo
```

La clave, dado que puede tener caracteres especiales o comillas simples dentro, es mejor ponerla entre comillas dobles.

Asociando los valores así, la lectura sería más simple y más clara:

```
$iniData = parse_ini_file("ruta/.conf/cf.php.ini");  #No se pasa true
$host=$iniData["host"];
$usuario=$inidDara["Usuario"]; #Ojo a la U mayúscula

... etc
```

Answer (score 1):

Otra forma sería comprobar si se esta llamado al archivo directamente y en caso de ser así  denegar el acceso o mostrar un mensaje o redirigir a otra página según te interese.

```
if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == basename(__FILE__)) 
{ die('<div class="alert alert-error">No Permitido</div>'); }
```

Si no te funcionara mediante las líneas de php, piensa en poner entonces un archivo .htaccess dentro de esa carpeta que deniegue el acceso a ese tipo de archivos con la sigiente directiva:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(htaccess|ini)$">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```