# Método para encriptar la conexión de la base de datos

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

¿Como están? he investigado sobre métodos para encriptar la conexión de la base de datos en php y mysql pero no logro poder hacerlo, que no se va nada de información, alguna ayuda ¿?

**Esta es mi conexión** 
[image: conexión]

```
 <?php

    /*Datos de conexion a la base de datos*/
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');//DB_HOST:  generalmente suele ser "127.0.0.1"
    define('DB_USER', 'root');//Usuario de tu base de datos
    define('DB_PASS', '');//Contraseña del usuario de la base de datos
    define('DB_NAME', 'sistemas');//Nombre de la base de datos

    $con=@mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    if(!$con){
        @die("<h2 style='text-align:center'>Imposible conectarse a la base de datos! </h2>".mysqli_error($con));
    }
    if (@mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        @die("Conexión falló: ".mysqli_connect_errno()." : ". mysqli_connect_error());
    }
?>
```

Comment: Una cosa que puedes hacer es guardarlas en un archivo, el cual podría estar en una carpeta oculta (fuera del root) y con acceso restringido solamente a usuarios de cierto nivel. [Aquí se explica más o menos esta técnica](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/221529/29967) . Ver también [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/56302/29967)

Comment: Muchas gracias @A.Cedano

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo mejor es siempre usar variables de entorno para ello.

**Cómo lo configuro?**

Hay varias formar de configurar el server, depende de cómo esté montado, algunas opciones son:

1. archivos .env
2. configuración de Apache/Nginx (o el que utilices)
3. si usas un hosting, a  veces estos mismos te dan herramientas para
   configurarlo
4. Si usas Docker, esto se pasa como parámetro al ejecutar el run

**Cómo usarlo?**

Es muy sencillo, utilizas la función `getenv()` de php:

```
<?php

define('DB_PASSWORD', getenv('DB_PASSWORD'));
define('DB_USER', getenv('DB_USER'));

?>
```

**Por qué utilizar lo de esta forma?**

1. porque te permite cambiar la configuración sin modificar tu
   código
2. porque te permite guardar tu código en cualquier gestor de versiones
   sin exponer tus claves
3. porque cualquiera de los formatos de configuración, no puede ser
   leídos por extraños porque es fácil tener y mantener diferentes
   claves (por ejemplo, para producción y para local)